# onload setInterval for carousel

Tags: javascript, html, carousel

I was messing around and making a simple carousel from scratch. At first I used `onclick="function()"` to toggle through the images, then I wanted to switch it out for an `onload="setInterval(function, 4000)"`, but that seems to have broken something...

Here is the html:

```
<div id="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-image" onload="setInterval(newImage(this), 4000)"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">1</div>
    <div class="carousel-image-off" onload="setInterval(newImage(this), 4000)"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">2</div>
    <div class="carousel-image-off" onload="setInterval(newImage(this), 4000)"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">3</div>
    <div class="carousel-image-off" onload="setInterval(newImage(this), 4000)"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">4</div>
    <div class="carousel-image-off" onload="setInterval(newImage(this), 4000)"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">5</div>
    <div class="carousel-image-off" onload="setInterval(newImage(this), 4000)"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">6</div>
</div>
```

And here is the script:

```
<script>
        var arr = 0;
        function newImage(el){
            var images = document.getElementById('carousel').children;
            for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++ ){
                images[i].className = "carousel-image-off";
            } if (arr < images.length-1){
                arr++;
                images[arr].className = "carousel-image";
            } else {
                arr = 0;
                images[arr].className = "carousel-image";
            }
        }
</script>
```

Comment: There's no onload on div , onload only works on body tag

Comment: Thank you. This is probably what I needed to hear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've simplified a little bit, changed a few things.

**HTML**

```
<div id="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-image active"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">1</div>
    <div class="carousel-image"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">2</div>
    <div class="carousel-image"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">3</div>
    <div class="carousel-image"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">4</div>
    <div class="carousel-image"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">5</div>
    <div class="carousel-image"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">6</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.carousel-image {
    display:none;
}
.carousel-image.active {
    display:inline;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
function newImage() {
    var images = document.getElementsByClassName('carousel-image');
    for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++ ) {
        if(images[i].className.match('active'))
        {
            images[i].classList.remove('active');
            if(i >= images.length-1)
            {
                images[0].classList.add('active');
            }
            else
            {
                images[i+1].classList.add('active');
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}

setInterval(
    newImage, 
    1000
);
```

**JSFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/nasd0ska/2/

**Note**

If I were you, I'd use jQuery. So easy and handy for manipulating DOM!

Comment: Your solution does seem a little less convoluted. I decided to go back and try my hand at some plain JS. Is it bad practice to concatenate classes though?

edit:
You'll have to excuse my newness. I'm quite sure that it isn't bad practice now that I think about it.

Comment: I used to work with plain JS. It's good to begin in order to fully understand Javascript before using an "assistant" like jQuery. Regarding classes, I don't know what you mean about "concatenate" classes but I generally prefer to use multiple distinct class to work with my code. `classList` helps a lot with that.

Comment: Hope I was able to help. Think about a little "+1" or "accepted answer" if you feel right about it :P